# Deleting Datadog logs after 7 days time frame

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, datadog

i am using datadog to monitor my cloud infrastructure(AWS). at present, i am sending aws-logs to datadog and datadog keeping those log data for some default timeframe.

**How i can set some limit so that after that particular limit logs will be deleted from datadog?**

**I want to delete datadog logs after 7 days**

**Can anyone suggest a solution for this.**

Comment: Have you tried to look for info on how to this on Datadog's documentation?

Comment: yes, i read most of the datadog documentation but didn't find it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Datadog keeps the logs for a period of time according to the billing plan you've selected: https://www.datadoghq.com/pricing/#section-log If you choose the 7 day plan, logs will be dropped from Datadog after 7 days.

The default plan seems to be 15 days, but there are other options between 3-60 days.